Out of range value for auto-increasement column in MySQL
I create a table using the following SQL.
CREATE TABLE `tt` (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `another_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`another_id`), KEY `idx_another_id` (`another_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 shardkey=another_id

I try to insert about 5,800,000 tuples into this table. But there is an error saying "Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1 Query".
I am really confused. The data type of column 'id' which is an auto increment column is unsigned int. The value of unsigned int can reach 4,294,967,295 which is far more bigger than 5,800,000. As the value of column 'id' is given by MySQL itself, it cannot be an negative number. How can this "out of value" error happens?

Did you attempt this once or lots(without truncate)? And what does an insert look like?

I attempt this lots with truncate. Acually, I just try to insert into an empty table. The SQL is like "INSERT INTO tt(another_id) VALUES (2315365)"

shardkey isn't an option as far as I know - do you have a reference for it? https://dbfiddle.uk/0JbM61D8

shardkey is an option for TDSQL for MySQL, part of Tencent Cloud. This is based on MySQL but it is not MySQL. Ref: https://www.tencentcloud.com/document/product/1042/38506

You will need to first run
select AUTO_INCREMENT
from information_schema.tables
where TAbLE_NAME = 'tt';

That's where your auto_increment currently is. It is clear that you want to insert much fewer records now than the amount allowed, but you will not be able to do so if auto_increment's current limit is too big. You can change the auto_increment value, but it can be tricky if you already have records. This would be the way to set it:
ALTER TABLE tt AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

but, you will need to find out why were you overflowing and whether you have records already.
